# How to get the pixel height of an inline background image via jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, height, inline, pixel

I want to get the height in pixels of the background-image of this HTML element via jQuery, how?

```
<section class="profile-banner" style="background: url(http://www.mydomain.com/images/myimage.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;"></section>
```

**update**

I now have this, but I never see the height alert box `alert('height:' + height);`.
Why?

```
    var url = $('.profile-banner').css('background-image').replace('url(', '').replace(')', '').replace("'", '').replace('"', '');
    alert(url);
    var bgImg = $('<img />');
    bgImg.hide();
    bgImg.bind('load', function()
    {
        var height = $(this).height();
        alert('height:' + height);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

you shoud do something like this

```
var url = $('#myDiv').css('background-image').replace('url(', '').replace(')', '').replace("'", '').replace('"', '');
var bgImg = $('<img />');
bgImg.hide();
bgImg.bind('load', function()
{
    var height = $(this).height();
    alert(height);
});
$('#myDiv').append(bgImg);
bgImg.attr('src', url);
```